# How to check points fall in rectangles and vice versa?

Tags: python, algorithm

Sorry if the title doesn't make it clear.

Here is the more detailed situation.

```
Given n dots and n rectangles.
Rectangles can overlap.
Dots are represented as (x,y) 
Rectangles are represented as (x,y,w,h)
x,y refer to location in x and y axes, respectively 
w,h refer to width and height, respectively 
How do i check if the following two conditions are met simultaneously:
each dot falls in a certain rectangle (doesn't matter which)
AND
each rectangle contains at least one dot.
```

Is there a better way instead of iterating through each dot and each rectangle?
It would be best if you can show me how to do this in python.
Thanks!

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: I'd recommend reading a book on computational geometry, which would provide the kinds of algorithms and data structures you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use what is called oriented surfaces created by the mathematician Gauss i believe. this allows you to calculate any polygon area. Using the point to test as a fifth point and one other rectangle point as sixth point (duplicate) you can calculate a new area for this new six-side polygon. You will obtain the same area or a bigger area depending on the point position compared to the rectangle.

---

## Addendum

The oriented surfaces allows you to calculate the area of any polygon when knowing their coordinates. The polygon must be defined as a set of points P(Xp,Yp) in the specific order describing the contour. Two consecutive points will be connected by a line.

In the picture below the polygon can be defined as the set [A,B,C,D], but also as [C,D,A,B] or [B,A,D,C].

[image]

It cannot be defined as [A,C,B,D] since this would define a polygon shaped like a butterfly wings as shown below.

[image]

### Oriented Surfaces

For each couple of ordered successive point - meaning [A,B], [B,C], [C,D], [D,A] for the defined set [A,B,C,D] for example - the formula allows us to calculate the area of the triangle formed by a couple and the axis origin. This surface is oriented - meaning it has a positive or a negative value - according to the rotation (clockwise or counter-clockwise). In the figure below the triangles (OAB) and (OBC) and (ODA) will have a negative area, while the triangle (OCD) will have a positive area. By adding all those area, one can notice that the result will be the area of polygon (A,B,C,D), which is negative because it is drawn clockwise.

[image]

### Calculations

You can find a clear example of the calculations and try a few things here: https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html. To complete my example I have drawn a polygon similar (but not identical) to the ones above on this website and the result is as follow: -22

[image]

### Adding a point

When you add a point, which is the point you want to test, you will obtain a 5-point polygon. The first thing you have to do is to place it in the correct order so that you don't have segments crossing. To do that you can create loop where the new point P is placed successively at the different positions in the set - meaning (PABCD), then (APBCD), etc until (ABCDP)- and calculate for each the area. The set giving you the maximum area in absolute value is the one you keep.

Here is an example from the website https://rechneronline.de/pi/simple-polygon.php. The first polygon is the initial, the second is badly defined and the last one is correctly defined.

[image] [image] [image]

One can see that that if the added point is outside the original polygon then the area is increased. At the opposite, if the added point is inside the original polygon, the area is decreased:

[image] [image] [image]

## Note

- If the original point set is not ordered correctly, you will have to reorder it as described just above
- In Python you will have to use ordered object such as a list
- To check that each rectangle has at least a point inside, you will have to check each point against all rectangles and maintain a dictionary describing which point is inside which rectangle
- Adding: I also realized that since a rectangle is convex it is possible to know whether a point P is inside by just checking the four oriented triangle area in order namely (ABP) (BCP) (CDP) and (DAP). If those four area have the same sign then P is inside the rectangle (ABCD), otherwise it is outside.

Comment: You also can use the point to test as a fifth point and if the area obtained is smaller than the rectangle one, it means the point is inside the rectangle. I guess that will required a reordering of the point to maximize the area. Order is important when calculating oriented surfaces.

Note: always rate answers and indicate whether it is accepted